# How to replay Recorded visitor movements on a webpage as an animation or movie type playback

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, screen

I recently saw a chat software which had an added bonus of "Visitor Recording" which involved the webpage sending an AJAX request every second or so with mouse movement positions.

In the chat service admin panel I could click a visitors record and hit a play button which played a video of where the user scrolled on the webpage and clicked on and more.

I looked in Google Dev tools to see how they are doing it and thats where I saw they send the mouse positions with AJAX like this image shows...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGUiy.png
[image]

---

**My question now is, how could a video of webpage be re-created to show a users visit using that type of data?**

---

Animated GIF shows an example video they created with this data...

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I was able to see the admin side and watch the movie and view dev tools on that page.

They load the actual webpage the user was on in an iframe and scale it down or up to the resolution/size the visitor saw it in and add a transparent DIV on top so you can hardly tell it's not a movie or image.

They then add the animated cursor coordinates on top.  They also scroll the iframe just like the visitor scrolled the page somehow too!

It's really unique how they stitch all this together to look like a movie of the visors visit to your webpages.

I am not sure how they animate those mouse positions and do the scrolling with them too but I am a step closer to knowing how it's done.

BTW the app is https://www.smartsupp.com/ you can create free trial account but you must email them to enable **visitor recording**

Anymore help would be great in figuring out the whole process to reproduce such a feature in my own app